# upload com ajax e formdata exibe erro

Tags: json, upload, formdata

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo para o servidor com ajax e php. Já tentei variações com o pessoal que tinha dúvida no mesmo assunto mas nada dá certo (tenho certeza que estou fazendo alguma besteira). Eu tenho um form com 4 campos, sendo um deles do tipo file. Faço toda a validação e na hora de enviar aparece o erro: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".

No form já coloquei o atributo "enctype="multipart/form-data".

Meu script está assim:

```
$("#formAgendaConsulta1").validate({
    // Define as regras
    unkeyup: false,
    rules:{
        arqup:{
            required: true
        },
        especialidade:{
            required: true
        },
        especialista:{
            required: true
        },
        dataConsulta:{  
            required:true, 
            dateBR:true 
        },
        horaConsulta:{ 
            required:true, 
            timeBR:true 
        }
    },
    // Define as mensagens de erro para cada regra
    messages:{
        arqup:{
            required: "Você deve selecionar o arquivo"
        },
        especialidade:{
            required: "Preenchimento obrigatório"
        },
        especialista:{
            required: "Preenchimento obrigatório"
        },
        dataConsulta:{ 
            required: "Preenchimento obrigatório", dateBR: "Data inválida" 
        },
        horaConsulta:{ 
            required: "Preenchimento obrigatório", timeBR: "Horário inválido" 
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function( form ){
        //var dados = $( form ).serialize();
        //dados.append('arqup', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0] );
        var dados = new FormData( document.querySelector('form') );         
        //formData.append('arqup', $("input[name='arqup']").prop('files')[0]);
        //formData.append('horaConsulta', $("input[name='horaConsulta']").val());
        dados.append( 'especialidade', $("#especialidade").val() );
        dados.append( 'dataConsulta', $("#dataConsulta").val() );
        dados.append( 'horaConsulta', $("#horaConsulta").val() );
        dados.append('imagem', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0] );
        console.log( dados );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $( form ).attr('action'), // "saveAgendaConsulta1.php",  
            data: dados,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (s) {
                        console.log('PROGRESSO', s); 
                    }, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function( data ){ // Executa a função se a requisição funcionar
                var msgFinal = data.msgFinal;
                $('#resultAgendaConsulta1').html( msgFinal );
                $('#resultAgendaConsulta1').show( 'slow' );
                // rolar a tela até o elemento
                //$('#cxAgendaConsulta1').animate({ scrollTop: $('#resultAgendaConsulta1').offset().top }, 'slow'); 
            },
            beforeSend: function(){ // Executa a função assim que a requisição for enviada
                $('#loadAgendaConsulta1').css({display:"block"});
            },
            complete: function(msg){ // Executa a função sempre que a requisição for executada
                $('#loadAgendaConsulta1').css({display:"none"});
            },
            error: function(){
                bootbox.alert("Falha de Conexão!<br />Não foi possível efetuar sua requisição.<br/>Aguarde alguns instantes e faça uma nova tentativa.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O envio e recepção de dados em AJAX é geralmente feito utilizando *strings* e você está enviando os dados como *object*, utilize a função `JSON.stringify()` para converter os dados antes de fazer o envio.

```
// ...
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $( form ).attr('action'), // "saveAgendaConsulta1.php",  
    data: JSON.stringify(dados),
    // ...
    });
```

Na recepção você precisará usar a `JSON.parse()` para conversão do JSON recebido (*string*) para um objeto do JavaScript; exceto se você estiver usando jQuery e aí é possível fazê-lo diretamente com `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: Giovanni fiz como vc disse mas continua o mesmo erro. No debug do navegador, em params, exibe apenas a palavra 'JSON' (acredito que não veio nenhuma string) e em response exibe o erro já mencionado.

Comment: Uma coisa que esqueci, coloque `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`para avisar à outra ponta que você está enviando um JSON, talvez resolva. E como você usa o **FormData** não precisa converter o objeto com `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Então o arquivo que recebe os dados já estava configurado como vc mencionou. Quanto ao FormData, o erro é exatamente o msm (com ou sem conversão). O engraçado é que olhando os exemplos do pessoal que usa o FormData, nenhum deles faz conversão e pelo que vi, eles não tem esse tipo de erro. O jquery que estou usando é a versão: v1.11.0 e o plugin jquery validade está na versão 1.11.1

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui e reparei que os objetos do FormData não são enviados como JSON e sim num formato de texto `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="chave1" Giovanni ...`, e talvez seja este o erro de validação dos dados. Quer que eu edite minha resposta para não usar o FormData?

Comment: Eae, Giovanni. Pode sim mas ainda assim permanece o problema para o envio do arquivo para o upload (input tipo 'file'). É estranho o porque desse erro. Pelos exemplos que vi aqui no site, o pessoal consegue enviar os dados com o FormData sem precisar converter; não sei porque o meu não envia. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o trecho `submitHandler: function( form ) { ... }` por

```js
submitHandler: function( form ) {

    // cria um objeto com os respectivos valores (ao efetuar as solicitações, será convertido)
    // "especialidade=valor&dataConsulta=###[...]""
    let obterDados = {
        "especialidade": $("#especialidade").val(),
        "dataConsulta": $("#dataConsulta").val(),
        "horaConsulta": $("#horaConsulta").val(),
        "imagem": $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]
    };

    const frmData = new FormData();

    for (let key in obterDados)
        Array.isArray(obterDados[key])
            ? obterDados[key].forEach(value => frmData.append(`${key}[]`, value))
            : frmData.append(key, obterDados[key]); 
}
```

e em `$.ajax({ ... })` altere o `data: dados` por `data: frmData`

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(form).attr("action"),
    data: frmData, // todo conteúdo armazenado no FormData() inicialmente..
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    xhr: function () {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (s) {
                console.log('PROGRESSO', s); 
            }, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
})

...
```

---

Desta forma poderá enviar **Textos** e **Arquivos** e o receptor de dados sendo o [php](/questions/tagged/php) poderá utilizar a variável `$_POST["chave-que-deseja"]` e a *função* `move_uploaded_file()` para receber os respectivos arquivos submitados no formulário.